# /bin/sh: apt-get: not found

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, aspell

I am trying to change a dockerFile to work with aspell. I have a bash script that I want to wrap in a dock

> Step 4: Wrap the script in a Docker container.
>
> The sample SDK we downloaded earlier contains an example of an action wrapped in a Docker container. In particular, the sample SDK includes a Dockerfile that builds the C program in client/example.c and installs the binary as /blackbox/client/action .
>
> The key line in the sample Dockerfile is:
>
> ```
> RUN cd /blackbox/client; gcc -o action example.c
> ```
>
> Instead of compiling example.c and installing the binary as an action, we’ll change the Dockerfile to install aspell into the Linux environment, and then install our action.sh script as the executable action command.
>
> To do so, we delete the RUN command above, and insert the following commands into the Dockerfile:
>
> ```
> RUN apt-get install -y aspell
> RUN rm -f /blackbox/client/action
> ADD action.sh /blackbox/client/action
> ```

I am trying to do this on the dockerfile below

```
# Dockerfile for example whisk docker action
FROM openwhisk/dockerskeleton

ENV FLASK_PROXY_PORT 8080

### Add source file(s)
ADD example.c /action/example.c

RUN sudo apt-get install -y aspell
RUN rm -f /blackbox/client/action
ADD action.sh /blackbox/client/action

CMD ["/home/huseyin/bin", "-c", "cd actionProxy && python -u actionproxy.py"]
```

The tutorial is outdated so I can't figure out how to make it work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The docker container isn't Debian based? If it isn't Debian based, apt package management won't work.

Comment: I was in a very silly position basically unrelated to the current question, but maybe can save another Googler who lands here -- I had run `docker run ubuntu:latest` when I meant to run `docker run -it ubuntu:latest`. I thought I was running `apt-get` inside the container, but it was actually in Mac terminal. whoops.

Answer (score 661, accepted):

The [image you're using](https://hub.docker.com/r/openwhisk/dockerskeleton/~/dockerfile/) is [Alpine based](https://alpinelinux.org), so you can't use `apt-get` because it's Ubuntu's package manager.

To fix this just use:

`apk update` and `apk add`

Comment: Does this undermine the reasons for using Alpine to begin with or does it still keep the Alpine image considerably light weight?

Comment: how to change the below command? https://hub.docker.com/r/buildkite/puppeteer/dockerfile

Comment: ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied
ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission denied

Comment: Still getting the same error after doing adding this to Dockerfile.

Answer (score 83):

If you are looking inside dockerfile while creating image, add this line:

```
RUN apk add --update yourPackageName
```